# GameAudio Middleware Differences

Tags: gameaudio, mobile, implementation

With the audio middleware systems like UDK, Wwise, Fmod and Unity opening their doors to the mobile market, I had a quick question about the differences between the packages you create working on mobile devices.

If you are working within Unity or Wwise, do you create a package and then choose on export to a specific device: mobile - console - PC ?

If you can't, does that mean you have to make a copy of the script in a mobile edition of the software? (I have seen that some charge a fee for just downloading the license)

Cheers,

---

**UPDATE:** 8.31.11

Unity Mobile - .Ogg compression does NOT work. Everything else works exactly the same.

*Audio Filters are not included in the Free download. Both Pro versions for Unity and Unity iOS cost $1500 each*

UDK -

Wwise -

Fmod -

Comment: Also, since XNA works for Windows Mobile, you probably want to include XACT as well.  I don't have any experience with it on the mobile platform, though.

Comment: Curtis, have you tried asking over at the Game Audio Forum? (http://www.gameaudioforum.com/phpBB3/)

I don't go there too often since Designing Sound and SSD are so good, but someone there might have a quick answer for you..

Comment: @Dave Totally agree, gotta include all of em! Will check out a download of that

@Luca I shall be surfing that site quite soon for sure - been there a few times - never for trying to pound out dents in my own lack of knowledge though hahaha

Answer (score 2):

You may all know this already, but just bare with me and I'll get round to trying to answer the question...

FMOD and Wwise are Middleware Solutions - Unity and UDK are game engines. The reason why this is an important distinction is that both Unity and UDK (correct me if I am wrong) are running the FMOD API as the basis of their audio solution. Both UDK and Unity just use their own graphical interface instead of the FMOD designer. With UDK and Unity (both of which I have used but not extensively so my memory may be failing me) the sound bank building is done when you build the game. So you would have to choose the platform you want to export to and then the soundbanks/packages build automatically. The platform would be e.g. Xbox, PS3, iOS etc. or which ever platforms you have license for, then you would transfer the game to that platform and it should work.

With FMOD and Wwise things can be slightly different cause you can manually build soundbanks straight from the designer tool. If you have a game that has integrated the designer versions of FMOD or Wwise, choose the target platform, and create the sound banks. You would usually point the soundbanks to be built to a specific directory inside the game assets directory. Different platforms would have different paths. You would then copy the game to the target platform and play.

So to answer your question - you should just be able to choose the target platform and build the banks without getting your hands dirty with scripts and code. BUT if you are using FMOD or Wwise middleware then what you do after the sound bank building is very much at the discretion of how well these are coded into the game.

Also to export audio for a platform e.g. iOS then you will need the iOS License otherwise it won't work.

Out of curiosity though what are you trying to do? It 'sounds' interesting :)

Comment: @RedSonic01 Sweet answer! In Unity you can export just the sounds in .unitypackage form. Does this keep the sounds implementation preferences? From reverb zones to pitch shifting, what file are these located in if they arent included in the export. Better yet, whats your email? I would like to pick your brain a bit more.

Comment: Yes this is probably getting a bit beyond the scope of this forum ;) you can contact here - richard dot lapington at remedygames dot com

Answer (score 1):

My knowledge of other middle-ware tools is limited, but I know that in Wwise you work on one project and then generate the content for whatever systems you need out of said project. Of course, this is is really only possible if you have a license for Wwise. Otherwise you're locked into PC only (maybe Mac as well...can't remember off the top of my head), but that shouldn't be a concern if you're working on a professional project (because you WILL need that license).

I believe that FMOD is similar (but can't confirm).

Comment: @Shaun The situation I am relating any information I receive is not considered the normal use. But thank ya for the input! Everything I get from you all is top-notch info!

Answer (score 1):

I mostly used FMOD so I'll speak up for it a little. It's the same as Wwise in that you use one project and then generate the content for each platform from that. It is possible to have multiple projects for one game if you decide to split things up that way. With out any licenses I believe you can generate for PC and Mac and possibly PS3. But the others won't show up till you've got the right SDK's installed.

Comment: @Matthew definitely! those other options dont show up unless you pay that lil extra eh? Its interesting why they take money if you use their product in a title, but then turn around and charge more money if you want to DEVELOP in their mobile version... whats the difference? Why try and collect twice when its the royalties they are after, not flat fees just to use their software for a specific device...